# Remove Archives in category title

Tags: theme-twenty-twelve, categories

How I can remove word "*Archives*" in head title in category page?
I'm using the Twenty Twelve theme and WordPress 4.

```
<head>
<title>"name of category" Archives  | "name of sites"</title>
</head>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, and it seems that the user who answered your question also misunderstood you. Please add a snapshot of what you need to remove

Comment: I've edited the question. At category page I get this and I want to get rid of "Archives".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using yoast SEO plugin then the easiest method is to remove the archive word from "`titles & metas-> Taxonomies->category`"

find:

```
%%term_title%% Archives %%page%% %%sep%% %%sitename%%
```

replace it with:

```
%%term_title%% %%page%% %%sep%% %%sitename%%
```

Comment: Sorry, I said that confusedly. I meant the word Archives in <head><title>.. I found what you advised me but nowhere the title of category sites.

Comment: Ok...i just edited my answer please check that in your site..

Comment: @sidlo: if you resolve the issue using this then please accept it as the answer

Answer (score 2):

Some points of interest:

- The code for `wp_title()` is located with /wp-includes/general-template.php.  This function performs two filters: `wp_title_parts` and `wp_title`, and in either instance you have the opportunity to manipulate the results of the standard `wp_title()`.
- Look at functions.php within the theme; the function `twentytwelve_wp_title` performs some magic specific to twentytwelve, and is activated using the `wp_title` filter with priority **10**.

If you're not familiar with filters, I strongly recommend you look into it before getting too fancy with this.  However, my suggested approach takes the following steps:

1. Allow WP and twentytwelve to do their thing.
2. Come along after the fact, and just before `wp_title()` returns its string we have an opportunity to manipulate it using the `wp_title` filter.

   - For this to work, we'll need to assume a priority of greater than **10** to ensure that we do our thing *after* twentytwelve has done its part.

Thus, I suggest the following function, invoked using the `wp_title` filter with a larger (executed later) priority of **11**:

```
function overwrite_twentytwelve_archives_title($title, $sep)
{
    // Look for the string " Archives" (note the leading space), 
    // and strip it out of $title:
    return preg_replace("/ Archives/", "", $title);
}
add_filter("wp_title", "overwrite_twentytwelve_archives_title", 11, 2);
```

I took some liberty here in assuming that there would be an extra space in front of "Archives" that had to be stripped out as well (noted in the comments); adjust accordingly if you so desire.  Basically, what I've suggested here is to allow Wordpress to go about its usual business, only to have the "Archives" bit stripped out just before it's actually displayed.  Please note that I haven't tested this to work correctly, and if it doesn't I would be happy to put it through the ringer on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Go this link (change [www.yourwebsite.com](http://www.yourwebsite.com) with your domain )

[www.yourwebsite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpseo_titles](http://www.yourwebsite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpseo_titles)

then click on the tab : Taxonomies

The first tab is your target