# Modify page title format (when using title-tag)

Tags: title, wp-head

Currently my page titles are handled by WordPress, in a call to wp_head (I have add_theme_support( 'title-tag' ) in functions.php). I'd like to change the page title format for category archives - currently these look like

```
<Category name> Archives - <Site name>
```

I'd like them just to be:

```
<Category name> - <Site name>
```

Is there a way of achieving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the Yoast SEO plugin (which it looks like you are) then [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/163023/96768) answer might help you

> If you are using yoast SEO plugin then the easiest method is to remove
>   the archive word from "titles & metas-> Taxonomies->category"
>
> find:
>
> %%term_title%% Archives %%page%% %%sep%% %%sitename%% replace it with:
>
> %%term_title%% %%page%% %%sep%% %%sitename%%

Alternatively you could try changing it using the `get_the_archive_title` filter as explained [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/179590/96768)

> ```
> add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', function ($title) {
>
> if ( is_category() ) {
>
>         $title = single_cat_title( '', false );
>
>     } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
>
>         $title = single_tag_title( '', false );
>
>     } elseif ( is_author() ) {
>
>         $title = '<span class="vcard">' . get_the_author() . '</span>' ;
>
>     }
>
> return $title;
>
> });
> ```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for both of these - went with the Yoast solution

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the wp_title hook, try this code it should work for you :

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'my_new_category_title', 10, 2 );

function my_new_category_title($title)
{
    if (is_category() || is_archive()) {
        $title = ' - '.get_bloginfo('name').' '.$title;
    } 
    return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to edit the title tag () and not what is at the top of the page you can do this:

```
// define the document_title_parts callback 
function filter_document_title_parts( $title ) { 
    if( is_category() ){
        $title[title] = str_replace( 'Archives', '', $title[title] );
    }
    return $title; 
}; 

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'filter_document_title_parts', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can change the default `Category Title` without using SEO plugins using a function by override the default filter `single_cat_title` as follow:

```
/**
* Add Custom Category Title
*/
add_filter( 'single_cat_title', 'custom_category_title', 10, 2 );
function custom_category_title( $title ) {
  if ( is_category() || is_archive() ) {
    $title = $title . ' Example';
  }
  return $title;
}
```

The output of the above code is:

Category Example